# Get current session value in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, session

At the top of the page, Before the html tag, I have this

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $str = "f=6&t=3&e=1&view=unread#unread";
    $_SESSION['params'] = $str;

?>
```

Inside the HTML in the head section I have this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
     var url = "http://beleuramyhome.org.au/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?"; 
     var args = "<?php echo $_SESSION['params'] ?>";
     url += args; 

     alert(url);
}
</script>
```

But what I get is this , Why?

```
http://beleuramyhome.org.au/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?<?php echo 
$_SESSION['params'] ?>
```

Instead of the combined strings?

Comment: Thanks because you HTML file doesn't parse PHP codes. What is your HTML file extension?

Comment: You cannot move your javascript with php code inside to a *.js file, or else the php code won't be parsed.
Also, keep an eye out for XSS vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If your `$_SESSION['params']` is an array then you need to implode it and then use the `urlencode()` PHP function to encode it

`urlencode(implode('&', $_SESSION['params']))`

else just use `urlencode()` PHP function  to encode your string

`urlencode($_SESSION['params'])`

I you still don't get required output, first check what type of data, or if any data, `$_SESSION['params']` returns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is clear that session is not array ! `$str = "f=6&t=3&e=1&view=unread#unread";`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, It is fixed - my page .php of course was corrupt, when I created a new page it all works as expected